# Setting an alias within an alias

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to be able do something like this:

```
> function gitb(){ git checkout -b $1; alias $1='git checkout $1'; }
> gitb sample
Switched to a new branch 'sample'
> git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
> sample
Switched to branch 'sample'
```

But, the function gitb doesn't behave as expected because:

```
> alias sample
alias sample='git checkout $1'
```

instead of

```
> alias sample
alias sample='git checkout sample'
```

Can anybody tell me how to achieve what I am trying to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn the difference between single and double quotes.

```
function gitb() { git checkout -b $1; alias $1="git checkout $1"; }
```

Comment: Double quotes? Is that like `''...''`
But, they don't appear as close to each other as yours do.

Comment: `"` is a distinct character; on US keyboards it's the character generated by shift + `'`.  ASCII value is `0x22`.